# How do I start a new Activity with an if-statement?

Tags: android, if-statement, android-activity

I basically want to start a new Activity, but here is the catch:
I want the new Activity to start, when an "if-statement" is true.
I created a simple counter and when the user reaches a certain number, lets say 10, the new activity should start.
Thanks in advance!

Here is some code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    //NUMBER FOR THE COUNTER
    public int mCount = 100;


    //SUBTRACTS 1 FROM THE COUNTER
    public void remove() {
        mCount--;
        if (mCount <= 0) mCount = 0;


    }

    //UPDATES THE COUNTER
    private void updateGui() {
        TextView textViewCount = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewCounter);
        String CountText = Integer.toString(mCount);
        textViewCount.setText(CountText);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

Comment: Post your code what you have tried.

Comment: Seriously ? U don't know how to write a if statement?

Comment: I tried to write an if-statement, but it didnt work :(

Comment: put the complete class here bro.. I cant see where u are going to use that remove() method, and updateGUI() method

Answer (score 3):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, newActivity.class);
if(counter == 10){
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that u have a button called b, which if pressed 100 times, u go to a new activity

```
Button b=(Button) findViewById(<BUTTON ID GOES HERE>);
b.setOnClickListener(new OnclickListener{
      if(mCount<= 0){
           Intent i =new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
           view.startActivity(i);
      }else{
           mCount--;
      }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

`if(counter == 10){
    startActivity(new Intent(this, NewActivityName.class));
}`

Comment: I tried something similar before I asked you guys, but it didnt work.
it says I cant start a new activity in an activity